# Take an image from google map

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with google map now. That is I dont know how to capture a picture from google map. I developed my app which used google map api ver3 and it can show multiple markers, lines, my app's icons, circles and many things like that. So, it's hard to use Google static map API url such as

[image]

> maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Boston,MA
>   &visible=77+Massachusetts+Ave,Cambridge,MA%7CHarvard+Square,Cambridge,MA&size=512x512&sensor=true_or_false

Hope everyone there suggest any solution for me! Thank you !
P/S: I used google map v3, asp.net.

Comment: Check out the static map documentation, you can add polygons and markers using the "path" and "markers" options: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: Example: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Boston,MA&visible=77+Massachusetts+Ave,Cambridge,MA%7CHarvard+Square,Cambridge,MA&size=512x512&sensor=true&markers=color:blue|label:A|42.3588,-71.0934&markers=color:red|label:B|42.4528,-71.1834